# Summing up values in jagged array

Tags: c#, .net, sum, jagged-arrays

i have a jagged array for getting the students and subject details, i have used 2 jagged array, one for student details (name and rollno) and another for the subject details (subject and marks), now i want to sum up all the marks of the particular student, can anyone tell me how could i go about it, below is my whole code.

```
public void GetStudentDetails()
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Please enter number of Students");
            int STUDENTS = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter number of Subjects");
            int SUBJECTS = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());    //0 is reserved for the student name, so the marks starts from the index 1, hence if you set the marks for 3, it will ask for 2 marks


            string[][] student_details = new string[STUDENTS][];
            string[][] subject_details = new string[SUBJECTS][];
            string[][] result_details = new string[STUDENTS][];

            StringBuilder stud_sub_info = new StringBuilder();
            stud_sub_info.Append("Name\tRoll-No\t");
            for (int a = 0; a < STUDENTS; a++)
            {
                student_details[a] = new string[STUDENTS * 2];
                for (int b = 0; b < 2; b++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Enter Student {0} {1}:", a + 1, (b == 0) ? "Name" : "Roll-No");
                    student_details[a][b] = Console.ReadLine();
                }
                for (int c = 0; c < SUBJECTS; c++)
                {
                    subject_details[c] = new string[SUBJECTS * 2];
                    for (int d = 0; d < 2; d++)
                    {
                        if (d == 0)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Enter Name for Subject {0}", c + 1);
                            subject_details[c][d] = Console.ReadLine();
                            stud_sub_info.Append(subject_details[c][d] + "\t");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Enter Marks for {0}", subject_details[c][d - 1]);
                            subject_details[c][d] = Console.ReadLine();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine(stud_sub_info.ToString());
            for (int a = 0; a < STUDENTS; a++)
            {
                for (int b = 0; b < 2; b++)
                {
                    Console.Write(student_details[a][b] + "\t");
                }
                for (int c = 0; c < SUBJECTS; c++)
                {
                    for (int d = 0; d < 2; d++)
                    {
                        Console.Write(subject_details[c][d] + "\t");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I certainly wouldn't use jagged arrays like this. It makes for difficult coding.

In your code, for example, you're capturing subject marks for each student, but when you do you wipe out the data for the previous students. The `subject_details` jagged array doesn't have an index for student. You're effectively overwriting data as you go. You need the array to be declared as `string[][][]`.

Here's your code, made simpler, that would work:

```
string[][] student_details = new string[STUDENTS][];
string[][][] subject_details = new string[STUDENTS][][];
string[][] result_details = new string[STUDENTS][];

for (int a = 0; a < STUDENTS; a++)
{
    student_details[a] = new string[STUDENTS * 2];
    subject_details[a] = new string[SUBJECTS][];
    Console.WriteLine("Enter Student {0} {1}:", a + 1, "Name");
    student_details[a][0] = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Enter Student {0} {1}:", a + 1, "Roll-No");
    student_details[a][1] = Console.ReadLine();
    for (int c = 0; c < SUBJECTS; c++)
    {
        subject_details[a][c] = new string[SUBJECTS * 2];
        Console.WriteLine("Enter Name for Subject {0}", c + 1);
        subject_details[a][c][0] = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Enter Marks for {0}", subject_details[a][c][0]);
        subject_details[a][c][1] = Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
for (int a = 0; a < STUDENTS; a++)
{
    Console.Write(student_details[a][0] + "\t");
    Console.Write(student_details[a][1] + "\t");
    for (int c = 0; c < SUBJECTS; c++)
    {
        Console.Write(subject_details[a][c][0] + "\t");
        Console.Write(subject_details[a][c][1] + "\t");
    }
}
```

Now given that we ignore that fact that every student has to have the same number of subjects and that you allow for non-numeric entry of subject scores you can use the following LINQ query to turn the jagged arrays into something workable.

```
var query =
    from i in Enumerable.Range(0, STUDENTS)
    let Name = student_details[i][0]
    let RollNo = student_details[i][1]
    let Subjects = (
        from j in Enumerable.Range(0, SUBJECTS)
        let Subject = subject_details[i][j][0]
        let Marks = int.Parse(subject_details[i][j][1])
        select new { Subject, Marks }
    )
    select new { Name, RollNo, Subjects };
```

This gives me a structure that looks like this:

[image: query data structure]

Now you can use this query to get the total marks:

```
var results =
    query
        .Select(x => new
        {
            x.Name,
            TotalMarks = x.Subjects.Sum(y => y.Marks)
        });
```

And now this looks like:

[image: total marks]

Comment: Your code worked like a charm, although need minor changes student_details[STUDENT * 2] and subject_details[SUBJECT * 2], here in both case (*2) is not required, as it creates the blank indices in the array, rest all fine, and best part is its neater then mine

Answer (score 2):

This would be much easier to do using Linq, Collections, and creating classes instead of jagged arrays. This would allow you to chain 1 Student to many Courses, and in each Course have many Assignments. Then Linq statements such as:

```
Sum(x => x.StudentGrade)
```

The following are the stubbed copies of what I would start out with just to get an idea of what I could do with sums, and other information:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace StudentManagement {
  public class Student {

    public static void Main(string[] args) {
      List<Student> students = new List<Student>();

      Console.Write("Enter number of students: ");
      int numStudents = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

      for (int i = 0; i < numStudents; i++) {
        Student s = new Student();
        students.Add(s);
      }

      Console.Write("Press any key to continue...");
      Console.ReadKey(true);
    }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public List<Course> Courses { get; set; }

    public Student() {
      this.Courses = new List<Course>();

      Console.Write("Enter First Name: ");
      this.FirstName = Console.ReadLine();

      Console.Write("Enter in number of courses: ");
      int numCourses = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

      for (int i = 0; i < numCourses; i++) {
        Course course = new Course();
        this.Courses.Add(course);
      }

    }
  }

  public class Course {
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Section { get; set; }
    public List<Assignment> Assignments { get; set; }

    public Course() {
      this.Assignments = new List<Assignment>();

      // Set Title, Code, Section
      Console.Write("Enter nuber of assignments: ");
      int numAssignments = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

      for ( int i = 0; i < numAssignments; i++) {
        Assignment assignment = new Assignment();
        this.Assignments.Add(assignment);
      }

    }
  }

  public class Assignment {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double MaxGrade { get; set; }
    public double StudentGrade { get; set; }

    public Assignment() {
      // Prompt for Name, MaxGrade, StudentGrade
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I absolutely agree, the array-heavy code took me 5 minutes to understand and another 5 minutes to decide whether I even have enough energy to compose a constructive answer. +1 to you.

Comment: Funny thing is my students did this assignment just 2 weeks ago in class when we were doing ownership chaining through collections and Linq.

Comment: @Damon: If you don't mind can you tell me how the loops will go on for taking the input from the user, i too consider your code would optimize performance.

Comment: @Abbas I just edited my post from yesterday to show you where to put the loops in the code. I did not put in the the code to generate the sums and that sort of thing. This should be enough to get you going.